# EF Core database design for storing blob data

Tags: oracle, database-design, entity-framework-core, blob

I has been asked to created a system that stores documents in a Oracle database.
And it has to be in Oracle, Not S3 (:

A users has many documents and each document has some meta data about the document and optional an attachment in form of a file (pdf,docx,png,jpg)

My design has 3 tables

- User (PK Id, ...)
- Document(PK Id, FK UserId, DocName, ...)
- DocumentAttachment(PK/FK DocumentId, BLOB data)

My question is about how to query and update the data using EF Core without loading the BLOB data and also showing if the document has an attachment.

I only need the blob data when a user downloads the document, the rest of the time I just need to show that this document has an attachment.

Should I just make one table for the all the document data and use dto's and projections when working with the data?

The Blazor Wasm form will have some input fields and a buttons for deleting or attaching a document.

Comment: One table for all blobs with an id and blob columns! Then you can get the blob only when you need it

Comment: "I only need the blob data when a user downloads the document, the rest of the time I just need to show that this document has an attachment." - Then do you really need to store it in the db? Can't you just store it on the server in a separate folder?